# IntelliJ debugger cannot find local variable in foreach loop

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm getting an error with IntelliJ when attempting to debug the following block:

```
1.  private boolean compareMatrices(Map<String, Map<String, Double> toCompare) {
2.      for (String c1 : this.keySet()) {
3.          Map<String, Double> thisRow = this.get(c1);
4.          Map<String, Double> otherRow = toCompare.get(c1);
5.
6.          for (Entry<String, Double> cell : thisRow.entrySet())
7.              if (!otherRow.get(cell.getKey()).equals(cell.getValue()))
8.                  return false;
9.      }
10.     return true;
11. }
```

I have placed a breakpoint on Line 7 with the condition `otherRow.get(cell.getKey()) == null` and get the `"Cannot find local variable cell"` error from the debugger whenever the breakpoint is hit. That error does not happen if I enclose the for block (Lines 6-8) in braces, like this:

```
1.  private boolean compareMatrices(Map<String, Map<String, Double> toCompare) {
2.      for (Stringc1 : this.keySet()) {
3.          Map<String, Double> thisRow = this.get(c1);
4.          Map<String, Double> otherRow = toCompare.get(c1);
5.
6.          for (Entry<String, Double> cell : thisRow.entrySet()) {
7.              if (!otherRow.get(cell.getKey()).equals(cell.getValue()))
8.                  return false;
10.         }
10.     }
11.     return true;
12. }
```

My question is, is the error coming from a configuration mistake I may have made, or is this really a bug relating to IntelliJ's misinterpretation of Java syntax? Also, do conditional breakpoints significantly slow down the debugger? When using the second version above, the debugger executes correctly, but takes over ten times longer than in normal execution.

Comment: Does it work without a conditional breakpoint? Could be a bug in the IDE

Comment: Yes it does, if the conditional breakpoint is removed (either removing the condition or the breakpoint), it works correctly.

Comment: Please share a sample project by creating new bug request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid java thus it cannot be a configuration mistake. I doubt that it's an IntelliJ bug. My guess is that you:

- compiled the programm with the brackets present
- run the program in debug mode
- removed the brackets
- executed the line with the breakpoint

and now your source code doesn't match the compiled one, hence the error.

Stop the execution, build your project again with the first version of the code and try debugging it again.

---

> Also, do conditional breakpoints significantly slow down the debugger?

Yes, it's possible. Field and method breakpoints are also significantly slower than "regular" ones.

Comment: Have tried, did not fix the error. It continues to accuse the same error. However, given the significant slowdown with using conditional breakpoints, I have switched over to having those checks directly in the source code, and inserting normal breakpoints into the relevant lines. That also seems to be safer in terms of checking the integrity of the data structures during normal execution: my use case does not have any valid scenarios where those conditions would happen (they are invariably a programming error), but it doesn't hurt to add them in.